# Issue when combing Plot and ArrayPlot using Show

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm trying to place the graph of a function generated by using `Plot` e.g.,

```
p2 = Plot[
   4 m^2,
   {m, 1, 50},
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red},
   PlotRange -> {1, 1000},
   ];
```

on top of a picture generated by `ArrayPlot`

```
p1 = ArrayPlot[
   Table[If[m == Round[1/2 Sqrt[n]], 1, 0], {n, 1, 1000}, {m, 1, 50}],
   ColorFunction -> "AlpineColors",
   FrameTicks -> Automatic,
   DataRange -> {{1, 50}, {1, 1000}}
   ];
```

in such a way that the origin and direction of the axes match (e.g., in `ArrayPlot` going to the right means the $x$-value is increasing, while going down means that $y$-value is decreasing. I want this to be true in my `Plot` as well).

Now if I currently run `Show[p1,p2]` I get something like this (at the bottom of the picture)
[image]
But what I want is something where the white stripe in `p1` matches the red
curve in `p2` (they are mathematically the same curve).

They way I thought of doing this was to set the `ScalingFunctions` option in `p2` to `{None, Reverse}` so that the $y$-axis goes down instead of up. However, when I did `Show[p1,p2]` after this I get `p1` placed entirely below `p2`, which is evidently not what I want.

[image]

I thought I could fix this by chaing the `AxesOrigin` option in `Show` to no avail. Is there anyway I can overlay these pictures so that the white stripe in `p1` matches the red curve in `p2`?

My code as of now is:

```
p1 = ArrayPlot[
   Table[
    If[m == Round[1/2 Sqrt[n]], 1, 0], {n, 1, 1000}, {m, 1, 50}],
   ColorFunction -> "AlpineColors",
   FrameTicks -> Automatic,
   DataRange -> {{1, 50}, {1, 1000}}
   ];
p2 = Plot[
   4 m^2,
   {m, 1, 50},
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red},
   PlotRange -> {1, 1000},
   ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Reverse"}
   ];
Show[{p1, p2}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `Reverse` the data of `ArrayPlot`.

```
data = Table[
  If[m == Round[1/2  Sqrt[n]], 1, 0], {n, 1, 1000}, {m, 1, 50}];
p1 = 
 ArrayPlot[Reverse[data], ColorFunction -> "AlpineColors", 
  FrameTicks -> Automatic, DataRange -> {{1, 50}, {1, 1000}}];
p2 = Plot[4  m^2, {m, 1, 50}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
   PlotRange -> {1, 1000}];
Show[p1, p2, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Damn why didn't I think of that. Thanks anyway tho.